# AWS Cognito CognitoIdentityCredentials not setting access values when calling S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have the same code that lives in two different environments. The difference, mainly, is different userpools/identityPools are used. One environment works fine, the other, when attempting to access S3 returns the error `Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.`

Looking at values passed/set when calling `CognitoIdentityCredentials` I noticed the one that works returns the `accessKey, data, and sessionToken` where the one that errors out does not. Those value are either `undefined` or `null`.

The code that makes that request is identical only that environment file is different, in values only. I've confirmed I'm providing the correct values for userPoolId, identityPoolId, and region.

I think I might have missed a permission or something in my other environment or something but I'm not sure what.

Call being made to CognitoIdentityCredentials:

```
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(
      {
        IdentityPoolId: this.cognito.identityPoolId,
        RoleArn: this.cognito.roleArn
      },
      {
        region: this.awsRegion
      }
    );
```

I've verified the correct values are being sent for both environments. However, as stated, one works (no errors and sets `accessKey, data, and sessionToken`) the other one does not work (errors and no values are set).

Comment: checking `Enable access to unauthenticated identities` resolves the issue but that's a security concern plus the working identityPool doesn't have this checked either.

Comment: The error mentioned makes it sound like it is missing authentication information. Ignore your working user pool/id pool for now. can you just post the code where you are calling CognitoIdentityCredentials?

Comment: I don't see any logins parameter. Have a look at the examples on this page. Are you passing tokens?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html

This page*

Answer (score 0):

When you configure access resources with Cognito you have two options:

1. Allow unauthenticated access
2. Not to allow unauthenticated access

When you do no allow unauthenticated users to access AWS resources, they need to sign in before they can obtain credentials. For this to work you need to:

1. Sign in
2. Obtain identity ID

```
const cognitoIdentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();
cognitoIdentity.getId({
    IdentityPoolId: here_is_your_identity_pool_id,
    Logins: {
        ['cognito-idp.here_is_your_region.amazonaws.com/here_is_your_user_pool_id']: 'here comes ID token'
    }
});
```

3. Exchange token for credentials

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: here_is_your_identity_pool_id,
    IdentityId: here_is_identity_id_obtained_previously,
    Logins: {
        ['cognito-idp.here_is_your_region.amazonaws.com/here_is_your_user_pool_id']: 'here comes ID token'
    }
});
```

The code you showed is only able to work with an unauthenticated user.